# why jquery .attr() become case sensitive in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i know that jquery `.attr()` is case insensitive to attribute name, but when i create an element from document created by code, it becomes case sensitive.

here is code sample that explain the problem:

```
var mydoc = document.implementation.createDocument('a:b','c',null);
var myElement = mydoc.createElement("myelement");
myElement.setAttribute("attr1","val1");

alert($(myElement).attr("attr1"));//val1
alert($(myElement).attr("Attr1"));//undefined! , why?

var myElement2 = document.createElement("myelement2");
myElement2.setAttribute("attr1","val1");

alert($(myElement2).attr("attr1"));//val1
alert($(myElement2).attr("Attr1"));//val1
```

i have tested it on chrome 22.0 and jquery 1.8.

**UPDATE:**

it seems that it is not `jquery` issue.

```
console.log(myElement.attributes['attr1']); //val1 , OK
console.log(myElement.attributes['Attr1']); //undefined ???

console.log(myElement2.attributes['attr1']); //val1 , OK
console.log(myElement2.attributes['Attr1']); //val1 , OK
```

Comment: not sure, maybe it converts all default attribute names to lowercase, but why do you need it to be case insensitive in the first place?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the first document is HTML while the second document is XML. HTML has case insensitive attribute names, XML doesn't.

Comment: Attribute names should always be lower case, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Virus721: Really? Neither HTML nor XML require attribute names to be lowercase (although XHTML does).

Comment: @Quentin curiously, I tried the OP's code having created an apparently valid HTML `DocumentType` node for it, and it was still case sensitive.

Comment: @Virus721 not in the case of SVG attributes, such as startOffset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a documentType (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMImplementation.createDocumentType) of html and pass it to the `createDocument` method as the 3rd parameter

```
var dt = document.implementation.createDocumentType('html', '', '');
var mydoc = document.implementation.createDocument('a:b','c',dt);

var myElement = mydoc.createElement("myelement");
myElement.setAttribute("attr1","val1");

console.log(myElement.attributes['attr1']); //val1 , OK
console.log(myElement.attributes['Attr1']); //val1 , OK !!!
```

Comment: how about `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument()`?

Comment: @Ouadie, that would do the same thing. I just considered the OPs initial code in-case the extra parameters of `createDocument` are required..

Answer (score 1):

it's due to the type of documents, just specify the type of document (HTML for example):

```
var mydoc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/wwNhw/